# Is there such thing as a parallel linked list?

Tags: sorting, parallel-processing, linked-list

Ok so basically, i'm not asking for source code or anything, but essentially I'm writing a scholarship program where the user can store all the scholarships that they're interested in. Thus, they input the info (name, deadline, award amount, etc), and they do this everytime they wanna add something new to the list.

As for my problem, I want to be able to have a sort method that sorts it how they choose, so alphabetical order, most money awarded, etc. I'm trying to do it with a linked list, where one list is for names and another for the deadline, and the other things listed above, but when I sort it based on one criteria, how can I make the other list sort the same way?

Is this possible another way with a linked list or am I going about this the completely wrong way?

btw I know you can do it with arrays, but i'm hoping to score extra points on my assignment with a linked list.

Comment: Instead of having a separate list for each type of data, it would probably be much simpler to have a single list where each node holds all the data for one student. Then you only have one list to sort.

Comment: Shouldn't be too difficult: where a 'standard' linked list has a pointer to the 'next' element, you'll want to incorporate pointer**s** to 'next in alphabetical order', 'next in monetary value', 'next in deadline date order', *etc*.  Then, for each of the usual operations on a linked list you'll have to write versions to maintain all the separate chains.  You'll give up fairly soon and come to the conclusion that a table of scholarships, which you can sort by any column(s) you choose, would have been a better idea to start with.

Comment: And, as for scoring extra points for tackling the problem in a needlessly complex way, ... I doubt it.

Answer (score 0):

> **Q** : *hoping to score extra points on my assignment with a linked list.*

If hunting extra points, you may cite, that this problem has been solved as early as half a century ago, by no smaller genius than Charles H. MOORE, the only man who never had to learn FORTH ( as he has created it ).

A lovely picture about multi-context linked-lists implemented in FORTH vocabularies, having for each context another, context-specific linked-list-pointers-{PREV|NEXT} was presented 40 years ago in Leo BRODIE's (a must-read book+) - "An Introduction to the FORTH Language and Operating System for Beginners and Professionals"

[image]

This system-level implementation in FORTH is smart and utmost efficient for any reasonable multi-processing accesses, be it either a just-**`[CONCURRENT]`** or a true-**`[PARALLEL]`** consumer-processing ( whereas the maintenance needs some form of transaction-level protection, during the network-of-pointers re-writes, doesn't it? )

+) Starting FORTH [Pg.242]; Leo BRODIE

Comment: But the illustration shows 3 separate linked lists, albeit all stored in one structure.  Each element has only a link to the next in its own list.  I think this is the solution to an inversion of the problem OP has set us.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark the **three-lanes-of-context** are obvious, aren't they? Sure, FORTH used a separate contexts ( because of them being separate ), yet the scheme is obivous - each item has {PREV|NEXT}-pointers in any "co-existent"-context of use - [ the alphabetic ordering, the financials ordering, a deadline ordering, a scientific value ordering, a travel expenses related ordering, ..., an Erdos number gain ordering, ... whateverelseonemaydesignasanorderablemetric, ... ] as necessary and plausible. Having this in late 60-ies in place is a lesson by itself, isn't it? :)